# Issue with c++ time function.

Tags: c++, time, datetime-format

So I am using function to get the time from time with an offset of 555550 which should give a value of 10:19:09. But when I use gmtime and asctime I get a value of 10 seconds instead of 9 seconds, and I don't understand why I am one second off. Could anyone please explain this?

Here is the code I am testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) 
{
    time_t now = 555550;
    printf ("The time is %s", asctime (localtime (&now)));
    printf ("UTC time is %s", asctime (gmtime (&now)));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 555550 => Wed, 07 Jan 1970 10:19:10 GMT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your calculation is wrong: see http://www.epochconverter.com/. 10 seconds is correct. How would a number divisible by 10 end up as 9 when modded by 60?

Answer (score 1):

according to http://www.epochconverter.com/ the value of 555550 is Wed, 07 Jan 1970 10:19:10 GMT, so your assumption about 555550 to be 10:19:09 was wrong.